# Receive offline message with XMPP

Tags: objective-c, xmppframework, ios8.1

I am working on a chat app using `XMPP` Protocol.
I tried following
[this tutorial](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)  from github . Everything is working fine using
`XMPP`.

But I'm unable to receive offline messages when user comes
online.
As user A is logged out and user B sends messages to user A, and when user A logs into app, it must receive all the messages that
were sent by user B during `offline session`.

**How can I receive these offline messages?**
My app is totally stuck on this issue. Please help if anyone
knows the solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Ok working.. I just added `#import "XMPPMessage+XEP_0184.h"` in `AppDelegate` and it works.

Comment: how did you do this? i Have added this class but i couldn't receive when i'm back online.Please help me to do this?

Comment: hello i am using swift code i am also stuck here can any one help to solve this issue....

Comment: anyone succeeded in this ?

Comment: How to get offline message in push notification in mobile side instantly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `mod_offline` on server, if you are using **ejabberd XMPP Server**.

Here is the code needs to enable module:

```
ignore_pep_from_offline: true
max_user_offline_messages: 
admin: 5000
all: 100
mod_offline: 
access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
```

Write this code in `ejabberd.yml` config file.
It will store unto 100 messages per user received when client was offline.

At client side, you may have to register for service:

```
'http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'
```

If you done this, whenever offline client gets online, server will send those stored messages to respective client.

Answer (score 0):

You've to send Request for offline message if server supports. XMPP works on TCP protocol so as soon as client is up, it should send request to server.

```
<iq type='get'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info' 
         node='http://jabber.org/protocol/offline'/>
</iq>
```